# Why is my JavaScript if statement not working?

Tags: javascript

The first `if` statement is not working although I passed the value of the block parameter as `physicalActivityBlock`:

```
function obj(select,block,idName) {
    var a=document.getElementById(select).value;
    var b=document.getElementById(block);
    var i=0;
    b.innerHTML = '';

   if(block=='physicalActivityBlock'){
       b.appendChild('<p>hello</p>');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` condition looks fine, but the code in the `if` block is wrong. [`appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) doesn't accept a string. It accepts a DOM node.

As you're using `innerHTML` anyway, you could do this:

```
if (block == 'physicalActivityBlock') {
    b.innerHTML = '<p>hello</p>';
}
```

I'd probably change the logic slightly so you only set `innerHTML` once:

```
function obj(select,block,idName) {
    var a=document.getElementById(select).value;
    var b=document.getElementById(block);
    var i=0;

   b.innerHTML = block=='physicalActivityBlock' ? '<p>hello</p>' : '';
}
```

If you really want to use `appendChild`, you'll have to create the element:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = 'hello';
b.appendChild(p);
```